# How much memory does a PNG image take up?

Tags: android, android-studio, png

In my app, I am going to have 750 PNG images in my drawable folder. I am getting these images by taking screenshots from my computer.

When I built my app with all of the images, the app's file size was 140MB. Then, When I removed all of the images and rebuilt it, it went down to 2.75 MB.

Is there any way to reduce the amount of memory the PNG images take up? Would reducing the size of my screenshot be an effective solution?

Comment: "the app's memory was 140MB" -- please explain **exactly** what you mean by "the app's memory". Do you mean the file size of the APK?

Comment: @CommonsWare On my testing device: Application Manager -> My App -> Storage -> App (2.75MB)

Comment: You can lower the resolution of your images, but it will reduce the quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am going to have 750 PNG images in my drawable folder

Most likely, that is not what you want. `res/drawable/` is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`. Your image will be resampled to match the density of the device, potentially taking up a lot more heap space. Usually, something like screenshots go in `res/drawable-nodpi/`, to indicate that the images should not be resampled based on density.

> When I built my app with all of the images, the app's memory was 140MB. Then, When I removed all of the images and rebuilt it, it went down to 2.75 MB.

I am going to interpret this as meaning the size of the APK, which in turn controls the starting amount of disk space associated with your app. Please understand that Android does not have an "Application Manager", even though your specific device might have such an app.

> Is there any way to reduce the amount of memory the PNG images take up? Would reducing the size of my screenshot be an effective solution?

If by "size" you mean "resolution", then that will reduce the file sizes of the PNG files and should reduce the file size of your APK.

As a now-deleted answer points out, you can also reduce the file size of the PNG files using tools like `pngquant`, that optimize the PNG in ways that your screenshot tool perhaps did not.

And, you can reduce the size of your APK by reducing the number of screenshots. How many of your users are really going to look at *750* screenshots? You might consider packaging a subset of those with the app, downloading additional ones as needed from some server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I may just resort to retrieving the png files from a server if reducing the resolution of the png file isn't effective.

Comment: @espa_network: Note that simply offloading the PNG files to a server will only help if you then download a subset of the 750. Packaging 750 PNG files in the APK will take up roughly the same amount of space as will downloading those same 750 PNG files. But, packaging 50 PNG files, and downloading an additional 100, will cut your storage by ~80%, because you have fewer files.